# Why does intro.js give me a "document is not defined" error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, velo, intro.js

I am trying to get the intro.js (https://introjs.com) javascript code to work on my Wix.com website, but I cannot get it to work.

I have the css file written into the header as described.
I have installed the npm package using their "velo" developer mode to my website, and my "Home.js" has this code:

```
import introJs from 'intro.js';

export function button1_click(event) {
    introJs().start();
}
```

However, when I click the button (after having added an html element with `data-intro`), I receive this error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is this code being run? Is it running in a web worker, or in node?

Comment: It's running in a front end file. The page calls it.